# Multiple source files in a C/C++ Application project ( NetBeans )

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, netbeans-7

I created a new C/C++ project via `File > New Project > C/C++ > C/C++ Application`.

However, under the `Source Files` folder, only 1 source file with `main` is allowed.

Is there any way to include more than 1 `main` source file in the `Source Files` folder ?

Or do I have to create a new project for each source file ?

In contrast, for each Java project, there can be many `.java` files in it. I am trying to find the same functionality for C/C++ applications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same project you could have many source files `*.c` and `*.h` and others

But for the same project you could have only one `main()` function in all of the source files

**Example:**

Code architecture:

```
.
└── source_folder
    ├── file1.c
    ├── file2.c
    └── main.c
```

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printfile1()
{
    printf("this is the file1.c\n");
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printfile2()
{
    printf("this is the file2.c\n");
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printfile1(); //prototype definition
void printfile2(); //prototype definition

int main()
{
    printfile1();
    printfile2();
}
```

Comment: Hmm so the `main` file in a project executes all the source files in the same project ? I am still new to C, kinda confused.

Comment: @TheKraven your main c file could contain a calls of functions which are defined in other C files. You have to define a prototype of theses function at the top of the main file before using them

Comment: Thanks alot, your example cleared up my confusion a fair bit :)

Answer (score 1):

you can have many source files of course (.c or .cpp .cu or else extensions/ simply add new source file) but only one main() function since this is the entry point to your program

Answer (score 0):

I had the same confusion and solved it using this method:

1. Create source files including the functions *(prototype and function body)* of different codes
2. Include these functions *(prototype and function calling segment)* in the main() file
3. Run the application.

----Works well----

Answer (score -1):

for same project,you can have a no. of sources files,but only one of those sources files can have a main() function.

same project :
              - sources files:
                            * 1st source file (without main())
                            * 2nd source file (without main())
                            * 3rd source file (without main())
                            * nth source file (without main())
                            * and only one source file with main().